# Кнопки не меняют цвет при использовании JSHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

Имеются две кнопки в HTML, хочу прописать функцию, которая заставит их менять цвет при нажатии:

**HTML**

```
<div class="buy_rent_buttons">
      <button
        style="border-radius: 3%; height: 3rem; width: 10rem"
        type="button"
        class="buy_rent btn btn-danger"
        id="buy_rent"
      >
        Buy
      </button>
      <button
        style="border-radius: 3%; height: 3rem; width: 10rem"
        type="button"
        class="buy_rent btn btn-danger"
        id="buy_rent"
      >
        Rent
      </button>
    </div>
```

Кнопки выбираю через JS и прописываю функцию, через которую назначаю им новый класс после клик-ивента:

**JS**

```
let buyRent = document.querySelector("#buy_rent");

buyRent.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  buyRent.classList.add("colored_btn");
})
```

**CSS**

```
   .colored_btn {
      background-color: green;
    }
```

Меняет цвет после клика только первая кнопка. QuerySelectorAll не работает вообще. Подскажите, как правильно сделать это?

Comment: Спасибо! Но даже если брать класс, а не ID, проблема сохраняется.

Answer (score 1):

- *inline*-стили - зло. Переносим в CSS и назначаем через класс.
- *ID* должен быть уникальным на странице, поэтому добавляем, например, порядковый номер.
- Тегу `<button>` не нужен атрибут `type="button"`. Масло масляное. Убираем.
- Если действия одинаковые, то лучше использовать [делегирование](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-delegation), вместо назначения обработчика каждой кнопке.

```js
// Получаем контейнер с кнопками
let buyRentButtons = document.querySelector('.buy_rent_buttons');
/* Добавляем контейнеру обработчик */
buyRentButtons.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
  // Если кликнули не по кнопке, тогда выходим из функции
  if (ev.target.tagName != 'BUTTON') return false;
  // Добавляем нужный класс
  ev.target.classList.add('colored_btn');
});
```

```css
.btn { height: 3rem; width: 10rem; border-radius: 3%; }
.colored_btn { background-color: green; }
```

```html
<div class="buy_rent_buttons">
  <button class="buy_rent btn btn-danger" id="buy_rent-1">Buy</button>
  <button class="buy_rent btn btn-danger" id="buy_rent-2">Rent</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает. Спасибо!